# How to change the order number

Tags: ubercart

My site is new and as in the below text the "**order number**" has reached only 57. But without creating any products in real I want the product number to start at some 500. So if a customer buys a product tomorrow, he/she should get "order number" as 500.

I understand we can change the product number in field:order_id  table uc_orders by creating a dummy record with order_id of 499 or so. But will it affect anything else?

> Order Grand Total:    Rs. 20.00  Payment
>   Method:   Bank Transfer 
>  To:  Reason
>   for payment: **order number** 57

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using Drupal 6, the [Ubercart FAQ](http://www.ubercart.org/faq) on [How do I set/reset the starting order number for my store?](http://www.ubercart.org/faq/2892) suggests using of the following:

```
alter table uc_orders auto_increment = 999;
```

I've used that technique on a couple of sites without any problems.